# Acceleration and Mass

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, acceleration, projectile

If a bullet is fired at an acceleration from a ship, how can I find the ships own recoil acceleration? Assume I have the mass of both the bullet and the ship and the acceleration from the bullet.

Comment: Welcome to Physics Stack Exchange! Please note that Physics.StackExchange is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for “check my work” problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic). You might get a better response at a more appropriate site.  [Here’s one to consider.](http://www.physicsforums.com), but there are others.

Comment: I am not asking for an answer, just for a tip or some guide to help solve or start solving it.

Comment: Tip : Conservation of momentum. Or Newton's 3rd Law.

Comment: I am at a loss to know why this question was upvoted.  Even a websearch on the word "recoil" would provide an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're probably wanting to look at Newton's third law. Recall that if you apply a certain force to the bullet, the bullet is applying a certain force back. You would apply $F = ma$ to then calculate the recoil. Hint: the reason why there is a large acceleration for the bullet and a very small acceleration for the ship's recoil, this is because it's the same $F$, but $m$ is much larger with the ship, so $a$ is much smaller.

Comment: Thank you VERY much, I really appreciate you taking the time to answer and help me :) God bless

Comment: You're welcome! And if this resolved your question, please click the checkmark on the left to mark as resolved.